# Скомпилировать драйвер для 2.8" TFT + Touch Shield Board v2.1 (ILI9341) - Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: c++, linux

[Исходник драйвера](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/blob/master/fb_ili9341.c)

Второй день бьюсь, не могу скомпилировать драйвер, может кто скомпилировать?

---

из комментариев:

Пробовал по [этой инструкции](http://habrahabr.ru/post/106702) - не получилось:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# git clone https://github.com/notro/fbtft.git
Cloning into 'fbtft'...
remote: Counting objects: 1060, done.
remote: Total 1060 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1060/1060), 491.83 KiB | 190 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (665/665), done.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cd fbtft
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/fbtft# make
grep config Kconfig | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's@^@CONFIG_@; s@$@=m@' > .config
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Пробовал даже свой Makefile:

```
obj-m += fb_ili9341.c
all:
  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Пробовал по этой инструкции: http://habrahabr.ru/post/106702/ - не получилось :(

Comment: @ReaGedCorp, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Expert, http://pastebin.com/hh12u3BH
Пробовал даже свой Makefile:
obj-m += fb_ili9341.c
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

Answer (score 2):

> make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.

скорее всего, у вас не установлен пакет с заголовочными файлами от используемой вами версии программы *linux*.

установить его можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

после этого в каталоге `/lib/modules/3.12.28+/` должна появиться «мягкая» ссылка (symlink) с именем `build` на каталог, куда эти заголовочные файлы установились (скорее всего, `/usr/include/...`).

---

объяснение: для сборки модулей для программы *linux* нужны заголовочные файлы **именно к той версии программы**, в которую вы этот модуль собираетесь загружать. уточняйте у того, кто собирал вам программу *linux*, где взять заголовочные файлы именно к этой версии.

если получите их в виде каталога, то надо самому сделать символическую ссылку `build` на этот каталог (именно её и не хватает вам для сборки):

```
$ sudo ln -s /путь/к/заголовочным/файлам/ /lib/modules/<версия>/build
```